# Datatables add class to all body rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm new in Datatables and I have a table that displays just the first 10 rows by default. I'm trying to add this class to all rows, not just for the default 10 ...

```
var table = $("#datatable-buttons").DataTable({...})
table.rows.removeClass('selected')
```

and

```
$('tbody tr').removeClass('selected')
```

and

```
$(tables.table().body()).removeClass('selected')
```

but without any success :(
Is it possible to add/remove the `select` class to all rows just by clicking a button?

Comment: I believe it is. But Is there a fiddle or sth so that we can see the whole picture.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe the best way to add a certain class to all rows is upon initialization :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  createdRow: function ( row, data, index ) {
     $(row).addClass('selected')
  } 
})
```

You can add/remove a class to a row upon click by using

```
table.on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {
  var $row = table.row(this).nodes().to$();
  var hasClass = $row.hasClass('selected');
  if (hasClass) {
    $row.removeClass('selected')
  } else {
    $row.addClass('selected')
  }
})
```

You can also by code remove (or add) a class to all rows by

```
table.rows().every(function() {
  this.nodes().to$().removeClass('selected')
})
```

All examples in action here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/c67q2b4x/**

Comment: As jquery is in use, toggleClass('selected') is easier to use when adding/removing class onClick.

Answer (score 0):

To add class to all the rows

```
$('#datatable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
  $('#datatable tbody tr').addClass('selected');
}
```

To remove class from all the rows (and select only the one you clicked)

```
$('#datatable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {

  // Removing all the selections
  $('#datatable tbody tr').removeClass('selected');

  // selecting the on which you clicked
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: You miss the point. You need to go through the API in order to keep changes persistent. The suggested jQuery calls will be lost as soon the user for example change page, filter or sort on another column.  This is why I work on a $row in the accepted answer. But using toggleClass instead of an if statement is surely a good idea.

Comment: Question is not about "making changes persistent", just altering the classes. There is no need to make things more complicated than they are.

Comment: Have you ever used jQuery DataTables? DT work with an internal dataset that is not connected to DOM.